# Conditional Instructions for Bank Transfer Payment Method

Tags: payment-banktransfer

1.7.0.2 CE

I want to provide distinct instructions for the Bank Transfer Payment Method dependent/conditional on the Customers Billing Address Country.

If customer billing address country is AU then use 'Instructions AU'
else use 'Instructions USA'

I believe the file that handles the instructions is
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/payment/info/banktransfer.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * @see Mage_Payment_Block_Info
 */
?>
<p><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getMethod()->getTitle()) ?></p>
<?php if ($this->getInstructions()): ?>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo nl2br($this->getInstructions()) ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Ideally the instructions could be injected from a Static Block

Answer (score 1):

In  magento,Payment methods **instructions** ***does not*** taken from *CMS static block*.

It is **basically taken** from **instructions** field of *`each payment method setting`* `(admin>System>Configuration>Sales>Payment Methods>Select payment method)`.

For **banktransfer** payment method,it is taken from *admin>System>Configuration>Sales>Payment Methods>Banktransfer Instruction fields*

For your case,you want to ***sperate instructions basis billing country and instructions is manage from  cms static block*** then you can try below solution:

1. create two Cms static blocks
2. rewrite `Mage_Payment_Block_Form_Banktransfer` block class bcoz getInstructions() function the instruction will show

**Code:**

```
<?php class [ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Block_Form_Banktransfer extends Mage_Payment_Block_Form_Banktransfer{
        public function getInstructions()
        {       if(!Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin():         $checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();         $billAddress = $checkout->getBillingAddress();      $countryId = $billAddress->getCountryId();      if($countryId=='AU'){           $block = Mage::getModel('cms/block')
                    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                    ->load('AU_blockId');
                     $helper = Mage::helper('cms');
                    $processor = $helper->getBlockTemplateProcessor();
                    $html = $processor->filter($block->getContent());           $this->_instructions = $html;       }else{

                $block = Mage::getModel('cms/block')
                    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                    ->load('blockId_US');
                     $helper = Mage::helper('cms');
                    $processor = $helper->getBlockTemplateProcessor();
                    $html = $processor->filter($block->getContent());           $this->_instructions = $html;       }       endif;
            if (is_null($this->_instructions)) {
                $this->_instructions = $this->getMethod()->getInstructions();
            }
            return $this->_instructions;
        }    }
```

Comment: Thank you for tidying up the code in your reply.  I ended up using a different approach using multiple bank transfer payment methods 
https://github.com/webbuddy/MobWeb_MultipleBankTransferPaymentMethods
which in conjunction with other modules allows me to also enable/disable the various bank transfer methods on a per customer group basis.
I will however have a look at your solution as an alternative approach.